# JavaScript array object doesn't work with Highcharts when defined through jinja (Django 2.0)

Tags: javascript, python, django, highcharts, jinja2

I want to use data passed through a Django (2.0) view to my html template - but in JavaScript. I need it to plot an area chart with Highcharts. This is the code

```
context = {
    'values': butler.serve(progress) #this works fine
}
return render_to_response('appfolder/charts.html', context) #this works fine too
```

And this is the charts.html file

```
<script>
  var values_data = "{{ values }}";
  console.log(values_data); //output works
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script src="{% static 'appfolder/js/charts/progress.js%}"</script>
```

and this is my progress.js file

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Progress'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://example.com">' +
            'empty for now</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value / 1000000 + 'mn';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} churned out USD <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>million in revenue in {point.x}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            pointStart: 2015,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 2,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Company',
        data: values_data
    }]
});

console.log(values_data);  //output also works
```

When I load the page, the chart doesn't plot. However I console.log(values_data) gives me an array in my browser console:

```
[911523597.25, 911523597.25, 911523597.25, 911523597.25, 803997322.63, 802981867.89, 726720570.4, 679697869.95, 911523597.25, 911523597.25, 911523597.25, 911523597.25]
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values_data` is a string. You need to call `JSON.parse` to convert it to an array before passing it to Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks! IT WORKED!!

Comment: *sighs* 2 year later, the bug is just too clear. Thanks again